# Ember: Setting variable in template from controller

Tags: ember.js

I have a variable in my template called *someString* that I would like to set in my controller. I am getting a **Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined**.

How do I make the controller aware of the template variable(if that even is the solution to this problem)?

My template looks like this:

```html
{{#modal-dialog action="close" title="New Run"}}
  <form role="form" {{action "submit" on="submit"}}>
...
  {{input value=emailComparisonRunID class="form-control" placeholder="Comparison Run ID (optional)"}}
  <label><small>{{someString}}</small></label>
  <br>
...
  </form>
{{/modal-dialog}}
```

My controller looks like this:

```js
export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs: 'services',
  dataVer: '',

  watchEmailComparisonRunId: function() {
    var comparisonId = this.get('emailComparisonRunID');
    if(comparisonId == null) {
      comparisonId = 1;
    }

    var onIdFound = function(id) {
      console.log('FOUND');
      this.set('someString', 'FOUND');
    };

    var onIdNotFound = function(reason) {
      console.log('Not Found');
      this.set('someString', 'NOT FOUND')
    };

    this.get('store').find('run', comparisonId).then(onIdFound, onIdNotFound);

  }.observes('emailComparisonRunID'),
  
  ...
```

Comment: You could debug this by putting a breakpoint on the `this.set()` line and examining `this`. When you see that it is equal to `window`, that would be a great clue. By the way, congratulations on breaking out the functions for found and not found, it's a clean way of writing code that more people should follow.

Answer (score 0):

You're creating functions inside your observer, which are invoked with the wrong context. Update them to bind the context of their function:

```
var onIdFound = function(id) {
  console.log('FOUND');
  this.set('someString', 'FOUND');
}.bind(this);

var onIdNotFound = function(reason) {
  console.log('Not Found');
  this.set('someString', 'NOT FOUND')
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: In this day and age arrow functions might be a better solution.

Comment: Based on his use of `ObjectController`, he is on an older version of Ember that predates ember-cli and thus does not come with Babel. Therefore I chose the safe answer (but yes, in my own project I would have picked fat-arrow as the answer).